# Font transition when swapping fonts

Tags: html, css, performance, browser, fonts

I have an external font loading in from Google Fonts. I use `font-display: swap;` to fallback on a default font until the external font is loaded in. However when it swaps the fonts the transition is really abrupt.

Is there a way to transition this font swapping behaviour to have a fade transition for example?

Comment: looks like impossible. You maybe can use two div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use transitions or animations with font-family. However, you could try using two divs, each one with a different font. You hide the second div by default and then animate the first div's opacity to 0, and the second div's opacity to 1.